# Custom Headers in PHP SQL Query

Tags: php, html, postgresql

I have an html form that calls a php document on submit that downloads the values of a table as a csv file. My goal is to utilize the "as" within the select statement to achieve custom column headers within that document. For example, I would like to select tableNAME.address and print to the csv as "Site Location".

Here is a sample of the php along with a postgres query:

```
<?php
// show error messages
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);


 if( !empty($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) && (strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'post')===0)  ) {
// Create connection
$conn = pg_connect("host=MYHOST port=ACCESS dbname=DBNAME user=USERNAME password=PWORD");

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
echo "Did not connect.\n";
exit;
}
$result = pg_query($conn,
"
SELECT
tableNAME.address AS Address, 
tableNAME.city AS City, 
tableNAME.state_1 AS State, 
-- adds 0's if zip code is not long enough
  case length(tableNAME.zip)
    WHEN 5 THEN tableNAME.zip
    WHEN 4 THEN '0' || tableNAME.zip 
    WHEN 3 THEN '00' || tableNAME.zip
    END AS Zip
FROM 
  db.tableNAME
WHERE
  tableNAME.in_process = 'true' and
  tableNAME.shippiing = 'false' and
  tableNAME.soft_delete_id = '0' and
  tableNAME.status_1 <> 'Closed' and
  tableNAME.return_shipment = 'true'
ORDER BY
tableNAME.site_id asc;");

if (!$result) {
echo "Query failed.\n";
exit;
}

 $num_fields = pg_num_fields($result);
    $headers = array();

    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
    {
        $headers[] = pg_field_name($result , $i);
    }

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    if ($fp && $result)
    {
            header('Content-Type: text/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="ups_returns.csv"');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            fputcsv($fp, $headers);

            while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)) 
            {
                 fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
            }
            die;

}
        exit('It works');
    }
?>
```

I have tried different variations on using apostrophe's within the select as statement. For example...

```
tableNAME.address as '""Site Location""'
tableNAME.address as 'Site Location'
tableNAME.address as '"Site Location"'
```

None of these have worked... I believe the line of my code that may need to be altered is:

```
$headers = array();
```

However, I have no idea what I can do to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: We can't do much with "it doesn't work". _What's_ not working? What are you expecting? What are you getting? What errors show?

Comment: Did you try `"Site Location"` or in this case `\"Site Location\"`

Comment: Alex, The result is simply "address" as opposed to Address or Site Location.

Comment: Alex, I tried both of your suggestions and the result was "This Page is Not Working"

Answer (score 0):

I have found a resolution... Instead of using data from the query to determine headers I set them manually.

```
$headers = array('Site Location','City','State','Zip','Package Type','Weight','ShippingCode','TicketNumber','ReturnService','Return','BillTo','Attention','SiteID','PrintLabel');

//for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
//{
//    $headers[] = pg_field_name($result , $i);
//}
```